# search for text in classes using filter

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this html:

```
<td class="catName" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target=".category1">A</td>
<td class="catName" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target=".category2">B</td>
<td class="catName" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target=".category3">C</td>
```

I want to use the `filter` function to find the class that has the innerText "A".

Trying with:

```
jQuery(".catName").filter(item => jQuery(item).text() == "A");
```

But it doesn't work.

I am using `Jquery`. I have to use `filter`. And I have to use an `arrow function`.

Comment: Take a look at the spec. You might want [find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) instead of [filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In pure JavaScript (without jQuery):

- use [.querySelectorAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) to get a NodeList of the targeted selector elements
- use [Array.from()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) or using the Array [spread `...` syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) convert the  NodeList into an Array
- use [Array.prototype.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) with Arrow Function to iterate every Element in your Array and filter it by a specified boolean statement (into a new Array). From that point on you can use `Array.prototype.forEach()` to iterate your filtered Array of Elements:

```js
const elsCatName = document.querySelectorAll(".catName");
const catName_A = [...elsCatName].filter(el => el.textContent === "A");

// Use in example like:
catName_A.forEach(el => el.style.color = "red");
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="catName" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target=".category1">A</td>
      <td class="catName" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target=".category2">B</td>
      <td class="catName" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target=".category3">C</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

For completeness, in jQuery the above could be expressed like:

```js
$(".catName").filter((i, el) => el.textContent === "A").css({color: "red"});
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="catName" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target=".category1">A</td>
      <td class="catName" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target=".category2">B</td>
      <td class="catName" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target=".category3">C</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

or, if you need a lazy matching approach (might match `"XXA"` as well) — the jQuery's [`:contains()` Selector](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/#contains1)

```js
$(".catName:contains('A')").css({color: "red"});
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="catName" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target=".category1">A</td>
      <td class="catName" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target=".category2">B</td>
      <td class="catName" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target=".category3">C</td>
      <td class="catName" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target=".category3">XXAZZ</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Due to your markup being invalid stands nothing will work. You need to add some corresponding table elements.
2. The first argument of `filter` is `index`, and `item` is the second argument (which is the opposite way native JS array methods work).

In this example I'm filtering the cell with "A" and turning its background red.

```js
$(".catName").filter((index, item) => {
  return $(item).text() == "A";
}).css('background-color', 'red');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="catName" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target=".category1">A</td>
      <td class="catName" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target=".category2">B</td>
      <td class="catName" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target=".category3">C</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I know that using 2 arguments will work. I want it to work with 1 argument and without return, using only the native JS

Comment: Then convert the jQuery collection to to a JavaScript Array, and use `Array.prototype.filter()`, instead of `$.filter()`? Or - almost certainly better - use native JavaScript to both retrieve the elements, and then filter those elements.

Comment: *I want it to work with 1 argument and without return, using only the native JS* please reflect that in the question to avoid confusion.

Comment: Note that I'm _using_ an arrow function (like you requested) - just one that uses an explicit return. @NoamB. And your question says _nothing_ about using native JS.

Answer (score 0):

At a minimum `<td>` elements need to be wrapped inside `<table>` element tags for it to make sense to the DOM.

The other thing you need to change is that the JQuery `filter()` methods receives the `index` first, and the JQuery `item` as the second argument. So you need `filter((i, item) =>`

`$(".catName").filter((i, item) => $(item).text() == "A");`

See JSFiddle for full example:
https://jsfiddle.net/Lexdp7rt/

Comment: "*See JSFiddle for full example*" - no; please include the code of your answer *in* your answer. While a live demo elsewhere is welcome, it doesn't replace the obligation (and expectation) that the site should be self-contained.

Comment: The answer is self-contained. Everything needed is included. JSFiddle exists to provide an actual demonstration which this site cannot.

Comment: Yes, it can (see [Andy's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76551154/82548) as an example), for directions and guidance, see: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/82548 (over on [Meta]).